# AS3: Getting values of objects by referencing their name

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I'm reading XML and attaching values to objects in two seperate movieclips. Like this

```
Map01:
Marker01.name = hello there
Marker01.short = hel
Marker01.value = 12

Map02:
Marker02.name = hello there
Marker02.short = hel
Marker02.value = 99
```

Now I'm clicking on Marker01 in Map01 and get its name and value. I want to compare its value to that of Marker01 in Map02, using the name, or better yet .short because the names are long and use special characters/spaces. How do I do this? I've pretty much tried everything that seemed logical!

---

EDIT: sample code for clarification

```
var marker01:mc_marker = new mc_marker();
marker01.name="hello there";
marker01.short="abc";
marker01.val="99";
marker01.x=10;
marker01.y=10;
this.mc_map01.addChild(marker01);

var marker02:mc_marker = new mc_marker();
marker02.name="hello there";
marker02.short="abc";
marker02.val="20";
marker02.x=10;
marker02.y=10;
this.mc_map02.addChild(marker02);

marker01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, showMarkerInfo);
marker02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, showMarkerInfo);

function showMarkerInfo(event:MouseEvent):void {
    txt_ms.text=event.target.short;
    txt_mv.text=event.target.val;
    if (event.target.short==mc_map02.marker02.short){
        txt_mvi.text="here should be the marker02 value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Map01 and Map02 are MovieClips and each MC contains an Object Marker01. Is that right?

Comment: Yep! The objects are MCs too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo there. Map02 use Marker1 things.
If its a typo in Stackoverflow,

this.getChildByName( "Marker01" ) will return you the movieclip, buy its name. take care though, as "name" is what it searches for. You used "hello there" when you should put Marker01 as the name. I would suggest you put a property called "data" and put the xml info in it so it doesn't conflict.

In the end you have:
if( this.getChildByName( "Marker01" ).data.value == this.getChildByName( "Marker02" ).data.value ).

I assume this is because you generate Marker0X at runtime and you can't declare some variables and use them directly.

Browny points if you make "data" a instance of a custom class where you can compare two "data". If you need more help, add a comment ^_^

Comment: Uh, I don't really get this. Also yes, typo. I made a simplfied sample that should shed more light into the matter.. well if I can figure out how to post it $%$&%$&